# nothing following mongoose find() function runs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Pretty basic. Once I run this nothing else runs following this. Why is this? If you need more information, let me know.

```
// Find all Models.
Model.find(function(err, model) {
    for(var i = 0; i < feels.length; i++) {
        urls.push(model[i]._doc.information);
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature for the find method is as follows from the mongoose documentation.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

```
Model.find(conditions, [projection], [options], [callback])
```

The conditions are not optional.

If you actually have a model defined called Model I would try.

```
Model.find({}, function(err, model) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.dir(model);
    for(var i = 0; i < feels.length; i++) {
        urls.push(model[i]._doc.information);
    }   
});
```

If this is not the case, a little more detail would be great, which code is it exactly that is not running?

Comment: I think you need to read the marked duplicate as well, since you do not see the various problems here.